SqlitMagic Library Compiler generate issue
I have implemented the **SqlitMagic **library (https://github.com/SiimKinks/sqlitemagic) from Jitpack (https://jitpack.io/#SiimKinks/sqlitemagic/0.23.0) in my project.
The JAR files have been downloaded to the external library folder in Android Studio.
However, I'm encountering an issue where I cannot generate the ClassNameTable, SqliteMagic_ClassName_Handler, and ClassNameColumn generated classes while building the project. I also attempted to add (.jar and .pom) files in the local libs package but encountered the same issue.
Issue: [[Library setup images both local and online](https://i.sstatic.net/nSvGDjwP.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/4hGroGuL.png)
error: cannot find symbol
import com.siimkinks.sqlitemagic.BranchTable;
                                ^
  symbol:   class BranchTable
  location: package com.siimkinks.sqlitemagic

Please help me generate the compiler files.
I need to generate classes for the SqliteMagic library.
ClassNameTable, SqliteMagic_ClassName_Handler, and ClassNameColumn generated classes
